# Omit argument name after computed type

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Why does not the following not compile

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
void stuff(T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_trivial_v<T>, int>=0);
```

while this does

```
template<class T>
void stuff2(T, int=0);
```

It appears that the argument name is needed when its type is computed. If I build with -Wunused-parameter, is there a better solution than the `(void)x` trick?

Real usecase:

```
template<class SrcType, size_t N>
explicit constexpr ShortString(SrcType const (&src)[N]
                              , std::enable_if_t<(N>=1 && (N - 1 <= npos) && sizeof(SrcType)<=sizeof(value_type)), int> x = 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. A typo in `std::is_trivial_v<T>::value` - either drop `_v` or `::value`.
2. `>=` in `std::enable_if_t< ... >=0` ends up as a single token (a 'greater than' sign). You need to separate `>` and `=` with a space.

GCC is being rather unhelpful about the second issue:
`<source>:4:64: error: template argument 2 is invalid`

But Clang gives more insight:
`<source>:4:62: error: a space is required between a right angle bracket and an equals sign (use '> =')`